# how to add months value with datetime() function values

Tags: php

I'm trying to add months to the following value, which I'm getting from my database `2014-08-15 01:02:51`

Like i want to add 2 months with `2014-08-15 01:02:51` to get the result `2014-10-15 01:02:51` is there any way? I'm not getting the date time function but only getting its value from database as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dateStr = '2014-08-15 01:02:51';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($dateStr.' +2 months'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new \DateTime('2014-08-15 01:02:51');
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P2M'));
echo $date->format('c');
```

Output:

```
2014-10-15T01:02:51+00:00
```

[Sample here](https://eval.in/178487).

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime("2014-08-12"); 
echo $final = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+2 month", $time));
```

Try this.